# How to retrieve row data by MAX(date)?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

There is a table:

```
+---------+--------+---------------------+----------+
| user_id | marker | date                | trans_id |
+---------+--------+---------------------+----------+
|       6 | M      | 2013-08-27 11:45:24 |        5 |
|       6 | MA     | 2013-08-27 11:45:42 |        6 |
|       6 | A      | 2013-08-27 11:45:59 |        7 |
+---------+--------+---------------------+----------+
```

I tested query:
`SELECT  marker , MAX(date) AS maxdate
FROM  mytable 
WHERE  user_id =6`

but it isn't proper.
How you would write query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the latest record for every `user_id`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_id , MAX(date) date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                a.date = b.date
-- WHERE    a.user_id = 6         ==> if you want for specific user_id only
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1351d9/3)

Comment: And how can to have the same result but without subquery(JOIN)?

Comment: i can't think of any way without using subquery. this one is another method, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1351d9/5

Comment: Ok, in the first case the Explain shows us "Using temporary; Using filesort", and in second we have only "Using where". What that means? And which of the queries would better?

Comment: Look at my answer... Without subquery and the request is faster than yours.

Comment: @Fred you answer works for only `1 user_id`, what if the OP whats the latest records for every `user_id`?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the latest record for every `user_id`

```
SELECT
  a.user_id,
  b.marker,
  MAX(a.date) AS maxdate,
  b.trans_id
FROM TableName a
JOIN TableName b
  ON b.date = a.date AND a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id
ORDER BY a.date DESC;
```

`MAX()` is an aggregate function, just like `SUM()` and `COUNT()`. Those functions should be used in combination with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you want. If you want to have the recent row in your table the query is:

```
SELECT *  
FROM mytable 
WHERE (user_id =6 AND date =(SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable));
```

If you want to have the user list sorted by date of the most recent to the oldest, the query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE (user_id =6)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

If you want to have the user list sorted by date of the most oldest to the recent, the query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE (user_id =6)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Comment: First example is suitable for me. Please explain to me which of way would be better in current question: 1. Using subquery in WHERE clause or using JOIN statement

Comment: For this example subquery in "WHERE" is the best because it is a restriction query.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to join with a sub query (this is if you need all entries)

```
SELECT 
    marker, user_id, maxDate.date AS maxdate
FROM
    mytable as t1 join
    (select max(date) as date
    from mytable as t2
    where t2.user_id = 6
    group by user_id) as maxDate
WHERE
    user_id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

there are also such way http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d707/4

```
SELECT
user_id,
marker,
date,
trans_id
FROM TableName
where user_id=6
having date = (select max(date) from TableName where user_id=6)
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this.

```
SELECT marker , date 
FROM mytable 
WHERE user_id =6
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

No need to have join or subselect statement.

The order by clause will sort your results by date, then the limit clause will only select the first row.